# How to display paragraph marker in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, paragraph

Is it possible to display paragraph marker in Visual Studio Source Code Editor?
Eclipse has this option, is it implemented in Visual Studio?

thx

Comment: Perhaps defining what *you* mean by paragraph marker would help (not all VS users use Eclipse).

Comment: The paragraph mark or pilcrow (¶) represents a paragraph break.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow

Answer (score 4):

Go to Edit > Advanced > View Whitespace (or Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W)